# Creating user owned objects generating implicit "post" action in timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine

I've been trying to use Facebook's new "user owned" objects as a way to track progression/scores in a mobile Unity game, for the user and their friends. So for each "level" completed I create a new `myapp:level` object.

Whenever an object is created like this, though, it shows up in the user's activity log as "User posted Object Title". I mostly just want to use these objects as data storage, and as a way to for the app to query and display your friends' data. I only really want to post a custom action (e.g., `myapp:complete`) if the user explicitly chooses to share it from within the app.

Not only does it generate these posts, it also create a new custom object type in my app's type definitions, simply called "Object", and an action type called "Post" (which seems to actually be `og.posts`). I even have to submit this auto-generated Post action for review, which seems odd.

Can I somehow disable the post action or is it an intrinsic part of creating user owned objects? If I can't disable it, is there any way I can hide it from the user? I can't set `no_feed_story` on the action as the action is implicit from the object creation.

(Note, I'm not using the Facebook 3.5 SDK on iOS, but using the Prime31 Facebook plugin for Unity, on Android, but really I'm just sending graph requests as specified on the [Object API page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-object-api).)

Comment: Have you found a solution in the meantime? I'm sturggling with exactly the same issue. Btw., no reason to mark an asnwer when the question isn't answered.

Comment: No, sorry, never found the solution. I thought I might have gotten hold of the wrong end of the Object API stick, so went back to self-hosted object markup.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is the intention of Facebook user owned objects to act as a data store?

Anyway, the way the graph works is that all things you publish is an actually an action. Even when posting objects. What is published on the users timeline, is the action of posting this new data item to the social or open graph.

Bottom line: you cannot get rid of this posted thing, as it kind of defies the purpose of Facebook being open and social.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but surely this defeats the purpose of the Object API? What is the Object API but a data store? Just to be clear, I do want to publish stories based on the objects I store, just not necessarily every single object, and I want to control what the story is, not a generic "posted an object" style message.